# Rails 5: Ransack search bar not responding after input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

So I was changing the homepage of my application and included a new style to the search bar, the problem now is that the submit_tag is not working anymore, it just reloads the page.

Here is my home.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'choices.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'main.js' %>

 <div class="container">

 <div class="s003">
    <form>
      <div class="inner-form">
        <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Wein...", class: "form-control", id: "autolocation" %>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field third-wrap">
          <button class="btn-search">
            <%= submit_tag "Suchen", style: "color:white" %>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
$(function(){
  $('#autolocation').geocomplete();
});
</script>
```

Comment: remove form tag because you can't use nested form and i think you should know that `<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>` generate a form tag

Comment: What is happening in your log/stdout when you click on submit? Also what params are present in your controller?

Comment: @NirajKaushal thanks, I just copied the html and didn't see the form. Thank you!

Comment: is your problem fixed?